# An integral that seemingly has two distinct answers

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

For the indefinite integral:
$$\int \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} dx$$
I can use inverse trigonometric functions to obtain two answers: 
$c\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) +C$ and $-c\arccos\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) 
+C $.
Are the two antiderivatives equal somehow? If not, did I make a mistake?

P.S. I'm sorry if this question has been asked before. I asked again because I can't find a suitable answer. Feel free to mark as a repeat if there is a similar question with a suitable answer. Thanks!

Comment: $\arccos{t}+\arcsin{t} = \pi/2$ so it's the same set of anti-derivatives.

Comment: How does that make it the same? Does the integration constant come into play?

Comment: Yes, $\displaystyle c\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C  = c \left[\pi/2- \arccos\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right] +C= \frac{c\pi}{2}+C- c\arccos\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) = - c\arccos\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C'$ where $\displaystyle C' = \frac{c\pi}{2}+C$.

Comment: NOT a definite integral!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indefinite integral may have two different expressions as answer e.g. $I_1,I_2$ but their difference is always a constant free of $x$ namely $I_1-I_2=C$. Note that $I_1=c \arcsin(x/a)+C_1$ and $I_2=-c\arccos(x/a)+C_2$
We know that $\arcsin z+\arccos z=\pi/2$. Using this we see that
$$I_1-I_2=c[\arcsin (x/a)+\arccos(x/a)]+C_1-C_2=c\pi/2+C_1-C_2 = \text{a constant}.$$

On the other hand in definite integral this constant of integration cancels out when we take upper limit and lower limit, finally.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too obvious:

Going backwards, consider the derivative with respect to $x$ of:

$\frac{d}{dx}(c \arcsin (x/a)-c\arccos (x/a))$

$=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \equiv 0$;

Hence

$\arcsin (x/a) -\arccos (x/a)=$ const., and we are done.